# How to change TTL of current records in Google Cloud DNS?

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

How can the TTL of current records in Google Cloud DNS be changed? The TTL of the zone can be changed through the `gcloud dns records --zone=zone edit` command, by changing the ttl without adding any records. For existing records, do we need to delete then re-add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit an existing record, you are correct that you delete the existing record and add the updated version. See the example in the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/dns/records/#creating_editing_and_deleting_records

If you want to edit another record, put it in the 'deletions' list. Also put it in the 'additions' list and update the TTL there.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might be implied, you can simply use `gcloud dns record-sets export`, then make substitutions in the exported file, and thereafter simply use `gcloud dns record-sets import` with the flag `--delete-all-existing` to update your zone. That flag might seem drastic, but it is pretty straight forward.